# How can I maintain my system without a root password?

Tags: password, maintenance

Is there a default root password for maintenance for ubuntu? We have tried to reset the password and now it has a prompt for the root password for maintenance where do we go from here ? The computer that this is on is an acer aspire one ZG5 with a ssd

Comment: When are you getting this message?  Is it when trying to reset the password? Can you confirm the exact wording?

Answer (score 3):

There is no root password set by default on Ubuntu. It is an account which cannot be logged into, unless you do set a password for it.

If you are getting a prompt for *admin* access, or from the `sudo` command on the command line, then it is wanting the password for *your* user, not the root password.

Comment: how can i wipe the system it is an ssd or solid state hard drive so i can re-install the ubuntu op system and reset the computer

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: You can also set the root password by using: `sudo passwd root`

Comment: @Rob simply boot off the CD or USB flash drive you used to boot and install it in the first place. You can format the disk, repartition, etc… from there. You don't need root on the installed system to reinstall it.